# Why does squid reject this multipart-form-data POST from curl?

Tags: proxy, squid, curl

This fails:

```
$ curl --trace multipart-fail.log -F "source={}" http://127.0.0.1:3003/jslint
```

With a squid status 417 error, `ERR_INVALID_REQ`.

- [trace of failing curl request](http://gist.github.com/290037#file_multipart_fail.log)
- [trace of successful curl request](http://gist.github.com/290037#file_urlencoded_win.log) that uses urlencoding (curl -d) instead of multipart (curl -F)
- [formatted version of squid's error message](http://gist.github.com/290037#file_squid_error.txt)

I've never had this in practice through a web browser, so it's probably curl usage instead of squid, but if I tell curl not to use the squid proxy, the web application on the other end accepts it just fine.

(If there's a more appropriate StackExchange site for this, please let me know.)

Comment: Should probably go on ServerFault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squid doesn't support Expect: 100-continue, being a HTTP/1.0 device. Notice the response status code `417 Expectation failed`.

Curl *should* retry the request automatically, but it doesn't; instead, you need to suppress the Expect header; e.g.,

```
curl -H "Expect:" --trace multipart-fail.log -F "source={}" http://127.0.0.1:3003/jslint
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can configure Squid to simply ignore that request header...

Add in squid.conf:
ignore_expect_100 on

http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/ignore_expect_100/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles across this question and is getting the same problem with cURL in PHP (not the command line), try adding this line:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

After a long time I fixed this issue in the following manner..

```
//proxy server address
        $proxyServer="192.168.43.201";
//Proxy server port
        $proxyPort="3128";

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "$proxyServer:$proxyPort");
```

Reff:
http://djzone.im/2010/05/php-curl-ntlm-squid-proxy-authentication/

Hope this helps someone...